# Routing Error: No route matches [POST] "/topics/post_up_vote_path(post)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm working on an assignment for school and I'm receiving a routing error that I don't understand..  I'm trying to integrate a voting feature to allow users to up vote or down vote on various posts on the site.  However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/topics/post_up_vote_path(post)"
```

I recently updated my routes.rb file to look like this to implement shallow nesting:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index]
  end

  resources :posts, only: [] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]

    post '/up-vote' => 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
    post '/down-vote' => 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
  end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Now my routes for up_votes and down_votes look like this:

```
post_up_vote_path POST /posts/:post_id/up-vote(.:format) votes#up_vote
post_down_vote_path POST /posts/:post_id/down-vote(.:format) votes#down_vote
```

From the error I receive above it looks like my app is searching for /topics/post_up_vote_path(post) when it should be searching for /posts/:post_id/up-vote .  I'm a bit stuck at this point, not sure how to get things to route correctly..

Here's the relevant GitHub branch associated with this project for further reference to other files:

https://github.com/jlquaccia/Bloccit/tree/checkpoint-49-voting

Comment: Please include the relevant code where the error is triggered?

Comment: Post the output of `rake routes`. This will let us see the routes that rails knows about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your voter partial (`app/views/votes/_voter.html.erb`) you pass the string `'post_up_vote_path(post)'` as the url argument for `link_to`. You just need to get rid of the quotes, so change the `link_to` to this:

```
link_to " ", post_up_vote_path(post), class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post
```

You will have to do the same with the down vote link.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  Was the quotes all along..  Works fine now.